# Form not redirecting after verified by javascript

Tags: jquery, validation, registration

I use a code to verify my registration form: http://rickharrison.github.com/validate.js/
That's my customed code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

     <link href="./js/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="./js/ga.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/validate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


    <form name="createAccount" action="validate.php" method="POST">
        <label for="fname">First name:</label>
        <input name="fname" id="fname">

        <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
        <input name="lname" id="lname">
         <br/>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input name="email" id="email">
         <br/>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>   
        <input name="password" id="password" type="password">
         <br/>
        <label for="vPassword">Re-type password:</label> 
        <input name="vPassword" id="vPassword" type="password">
         <br/>
        <button class="button gray" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div class="success_box">Si jvois ca ben tbnk</div>
    <div class="error_box"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    new FormValidator('createAccount', [{
        name: 'fname', 
        display: 'Please enter your first name.',
        rules: 'required'
    }, {
        name: 'lname',
        display: 'Please enter your name.',
        rules: 'required'
    }, {
        name: 'email',
        display: 'Please enter a valid email address.',
        rules: 'valid_email'
    }, {
        name: 'password',
        display: 'Please enter a password of at least 8 characters.',
        rules: 'required|min_length[8]'
    }, {
        name: 'vPassword',
        display: 'The passwords do not match.',
        rules: 'required|matches[password]'
    },  ], function(errors, event) {
        var SELECTOR_ERRORS = $('.error_box'),
            SELECTOR_SUCCESS = $('.success_box');
        if (errors.length > 0) {
            SELECTOR_ERRORS.empty();

            for (var i = 0, errorLength = errors.length; i < errorLength; i++) {
                SELECTOR_ERRORS.append(errors[i].message + '<br />');
            }

            SELECTOR_SUCCESS.css({ display: 'none' });
            SELECTOR_ERRORS.fadeIn(200);
        } else {
            SELECTOR_ERRORS.css({ display: 'none' });
            SELECTOR_SUCCESS.fadeIn(200);
        }

        if (event && event.preventDefault) {
            event.preventDefault();
        } else if (event) {
            event.returnValue = false;
        }
    });

    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

I tried changing the "success_box" to a function to redirect to my validate.php page, but nothing worked.  I tried deleting everything to the success_box and make a function to redirect if the number of errors is 0

```
if (errors === 0){ window.location = "http://www.google.com/";}
```

But that didn't work either.  I'm out of answers...

Thanks!

Comment: "errors = 0" is an assignment statement, not a comparison. You need double or triple equals for comparison: "errors === 0"

Comment: Right, typo error, in my code i used === I'll fix that.

Comment: Where did you place this javascript code?  If you replace the `window.location = "http://www.google.com"` with an `alert("HERE");`, what happens? Do you see any errors in your console with Firebug?

Comment: I replaced the SELECTOR_SUCCESS and deleted all the code that had to do with it and placed the window.location = "http://www.google.com/"; code in there.  I added an alert and it works, but my page is redirected on submit without checking if there are errors.

Comment: Removed [tag:jquery-validate] tag... not the same plugin.

Comment: create a live demo in jsfiddle.net, always easier troubleshooting js in a browser console

Comment: gpasci was nice enough to make one to help me :) http://jsbin.com/uyagod/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Look it's working for real!!](http://jsbin.com/uyagod/3)

I just removed the comma `},  ], function(errors, event) {` after the last object in the validator rules array.

Ok now I understand. if you want your form to act as a regular form if data is valid just don't call `preventDefault()` for that case (because you want the default form behaviour).

Comment: Thank you for your help, guess I don't need my comma... But what I want is the page being redirected to my verify.php page if all the form is verified and OK.

Comment: well instead of showing a box use `window.location.href=”something";` in the `else {}` block

Comment: Wow awesome you got it right! Thanks for the jsbin, quite useful, I'll use this from now on to ask my questions.

Answer (score 0):

try

`if (errors == 0){ window.location = "http://www.google.com/";}`

you cannot use single `=` in a condition.

Comment: You can use the single, but instead of comparing values, it assigns it to the `error` variable and passes the condition as true, so this is not the issue....